# Drawing a graph with animated tokens in the broweser

Tags: javascript, canvas, web, svg, visualization

I have to implement a a "real-time" web application where some tokens are moving along the edges of a network graph.

The positions of the tokens on the graph are pushed from the server to all connected clients.

I am pretty confident that I can efficiently implement the pushing part with web-sockets.

However I have no experience in "graphics-heavy" web applications. What kind of technology/library/framework should I use to draw the network graph (which is static, once the page is loaded) and the tokens that move along the edges of the graph?

Intuitively I would go for SVG (but I have never used SVG so far), since that allows me to access the tokens as dom elements and to maipulate their position. Is this a good approach?
Are there any libraries/frameworks that are predestined for drawing network graphs in the browser?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Just use a DOM element with the position absolute or relative and update its position as needed.

Comment: Unless the design is more complicated than repositioning tokens overlaying on a static network map (as you describe), I would go with @Blindman67's solution so you don't have to learn a new skill set while you are doing your app. Consider html5 canvas when the design requires fast-moving, morphable components.